# No Intellisense method descriptions in Blazor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor

Should I be seeing method descriptions in the VS auto-completion feature when editing a .razor file in a Blazor project?

This is what I'm seeing (screenshot taken in a .razor file):
[image: Screenshot 1]

This is what I'm expecting (screenshot taken in a .cs file):
[image: Screenshot 2]

I'm on the latest VS 2019 version (16.7.3).

Comment: Have you used "Report a problem" to report this?

Comment: Not yet, I'm posting here first to make sure it's not specific to my setup

Comment: Whether bug or dependant on other factors i don't know. Can only confirm that intellisense is very finnicky in the actual .razor files. Sometimes simply requiring me to close Visual Studio and reopen it so it doesn't flag everything. (Have even had it prevent compilation on a non error). However, my personal preference is to have most fo the code block in a seperate file. And the intellisense works fine in there. You can simply make a class file and name it <PageName>.razor.cs. Make it a partial class and it works perfectly.

Comment: @DKramer, do you have the specific issue I'm talking about? I hear you on the code-behind files, but if I'm not the only one with the problem, it's still worthwhile to report if we want to see improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reported the issue to Microsoft and they have finally corrected this bug in the preview version of VS 2019. It will be available in the next mainstream version.